# Ubuntu 18.04 not recognizing CD/DVD

Tags: mount, dvd, cd

I am trying to copy files to a CD, but whenever I insert a disk, nothing shows up in the file manager.

I have been reading all over on why this is a problem, but none of the solutions I've found so far seem to lead to some breakthrough.

`lshw -C disk`

> ```
>   *-disk                    
>        description: ATA Disk
>        product: Samsung SSD 850
>        physical id: 0.0.0
>        bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
>        logical name: /dev/sda
>        version: 2B6Q
>        serial: S2RFNXAH102505Y
>        size: 931GiB (1TB)
>        capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
>        configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=0e778e00-1594-03a3-80e3-9d0365c5e800 logicalsectorsize=512
>        sectorsize=512
> ```

I have also edited fstab to include the following:

```
/dev/scd0  /media/cdrom0  udf,iso9660  user,noauto,exec,utf8  0  0
```

Also tried running the following commands:

```
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

I even tried inserting a dvd/cd that has something on it, but it is not recognized either. I have taken apart the dvd drive and all connections look right.

When I run `sudo hwinfo --cdrom`, I get no output

None of these solutions have worked. What other work arounds are there to try?

Comment: Which software are you using or trying to use to burn the CDs?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, I am trying to use `brasero`, but it is not able to find the cd.

Comment: Probably the drive itself isn't recognized for some reason or it's faulty. Does it detect CDs or DVDs with content?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, it detects nothing. But I had used it when I was still running 16.04 and it was working fine. Since the upgrade to 18.04 I haven't tried using any CD's or DVD's so I wasn't able to test that part. I've read that there are issues with playing DVDs on ubuntu 18.04, but I wasn't sure if this was related

Comment: Playing DVD-Video is unrelated. I suggest you try a live session with 16.04 and test it there. If it still works then we can be certain there's a software issue with 18.04 but if it doesn't then it's likely to be an hardware problem and a coincidence that it happened at the same time as the upgrade.

Comment: Hmm, ok I might just do that then.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Yea it' looking like a hardware issue. Tried the 16.04 livecd and still experienced the same issue